# How can we create email alert for Scheduler Job Collections

Tags: azure, collections, scheduler, jobs

How can we create email alert for Scheduler Job Collections 
for example : i have a situation where i have to create a heartbeat solution for REST APIs (configured in APIM), if any endpoint fails i want an email alert